# Domino Designer - Show Single Category in Calendar View

Tags: ide, calendar, lotus-notes, designer

Is there any way to use the Show Single Category feature within a calendar view?

The problem I have is that the first field in the view needs to be sorted based on the category that it will be searched with - but with a calendar view, the first field needs to be sorted in ascending order so that the calendar is created properly.

All i'm trying to do is populate a calendar and then make it possible to select a name from a list - which then shows only the appointments for that name in the calendar view.

Is anybody aware of any workarounds for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is currently not possible to filter calenders. we have the same problem using the calendar from extension library in xpages.